# What type of server will I need to create a music streaming website

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming

As I stated in the title, I want to create a music streaming website. Will I need special server such as dedicate or cloud server for this with around 500 User per day?

And streaming connection is the same as normal download connection or will it take more bandwidth?

EDIT - add more deails
I will stream on-demand content.

Let's say I will just allow 1 hour per day for a user and it can be 500 users simultaneously.

To describe more for "streaming connection vs normal download connection", what i meant was, normal download connection is what someone download a file or download a page. I want to know if it is different when someone stream a music or video file. Or the streaming is just work as user downloading a file?

Please let me know if you have some more questions.Thank you.

Comment: You need to be much more specific, and provide more information.  Are you streaming on-demand content, or doing a radio-style stream where everyone hears the same thing at the same time?  500 users per day... listening how long?  How many simultaneously?  And, what exactly do you mean by "normal download connection"?

Comment: Thanks for the respond Brad. Question is updated according to your comment.